# break array of objects into separate arrays based on a property

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, underscore.js

Say I have an array like this:

```
var arr = [
    {type:"orange", title:"First"},
    {type:"orange", title:"Second"},
    {type:"banana", title:"Third"},
    {type:"banana", title:"Fourth"}
];
```

and I want this to be split up into arrays that have objects which have same type so:

```
[{type:"orange", title:"First"},
{type:"orange", title:"Second"}]

[{type:"banana", title:"Third"},
{type:"banana", title:"Fourth"}]
```

But I want to do this generically so not having an if statement that specifies orange or banana

```
// not like this
for (prop in arr){
    if (arr[prop] === "banana"){
       //add to new array
    }
}
```

Thoughts? JQuery and Underscore are both options to use.

Comment: thanks for that really helpful response. changed the equals signs.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> JQuery and Underscore are both options to use.

[Underscore's `groupBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) does exactly what you need.

```
_.groupBy(arr, "type")
```

Answer (score 86):

This is an easy job for [`Array.reduce(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```javascript
function groupBy(arr, property) {
  return arr.reduce(function(memo, x) {
    if (!memo[x[property]]) { memo[x[property]] = []; }
    memo[x[property]].push(x);
    return memo;
  }, {});
}

var o = groupBy(arr, 'type'); // => {orange:[...], banana:[...]}
o.orange; // => [{"type":"orange","title":"First"},{"type":"orange","title":"Second"}]
o.banana; // => [{"type":"banana","title":"Third"},{"type":"banana","title":"Fourth"}]
```

Of course, if your target browser(s) do not support ECMAScript 262 5th edition then you'll have to implement "reduce" by yourself, or use a polyfill library, or choose another answer.

**[Update]** Here's a solution that should work with any version of JavaScript:

```javascript
function groupBy2(xs, prop) {
  var grouped = {};
  for (var i=0; i<xs.length; i++) {
    var p = xs[i][prop];
    if (!grouped[p]) { grouped[p] = []; }
    grouped[p].push(xs[i]);
  }
  return grouped;
}
```

Comment: Might want to also include a version which is compliant with more browsers. `reduce` is not supported by IE8-.

Comment: @TravisJ: yes, true, if your target browsers don't support EMCAScript 262 5th edition then you'll need to implement your own "reduce" function or choose one of the other answers.

Answer (score 18):

ES6 solution:

```
function groupBy(arr, property) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur[property]] = [...acc[cur[property]] || [], cur];
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

or completely ES6fy:

```
const groupBy = (arr, property) => {
    return arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      acc[cur[property]] = [...acc[cur[property]] || [], cur];
      return acc;
    }, {});
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Just for reference: when calling this function, *property* argument should be a string.

Answer (score 15):

This assumes an array of objects:

```
function groupBy(array, property) {
    var hash = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (!hash[array[i][property]]) hash[array[i][property]] = [];
        hash[array[i][property]].push(array[i]);
    }
    return hash;
}

groupBy(arr,'type')  // Object {orange: Array[2], banana: Array[2]}
groupBy(arr,'title') // Object {First: Array[1], Second: Array[1], Third: Array[1], Fourth: Array[1]}
```

Answer (score 10):

Just build a dictionary which holds the objects based on their title. You could do it like this:

js

```
var arr = [
{type:"orange", title:"First"},
 {type:"orange", title:"Second"},
 {type:"banana", title:"Third"},
 {type:"banana", title:"Fourth"}
];
var sorted = {};
for( var i = 0, max = arr.length; i < max ; i++ ){
 if( sorted[arr[i].type] == undefined ){
  sorted[arr[i].type] = [];
 }
 sorted[arr[i].type].push(arr[i]);
}
console.log(sorted["orange"]);
console.log(sorted["banana"]);
```

jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YJnM6/

Comment: Works great, also Kudos for calling the pattern a Dictionary!

Answer (score 8):

Typescript version.

```
/**
* Group object array by property
 * Example, groupBy(array, ( x: Props ) => x.id );
 * @param array
 * @param property
 */
export const groupBy = <T>(array: Array<T>, property: (x: T) => string): { [key: string]: Array<T> } =>
  array.reduce((memo: { [key: string]: Array<T> }, x: T) => {
    if (!memo[property(x)]) {
      memo[property(x)] = [];
    }
    memo[property(x)].push(x);
    return memo;
  }, {});

export default groupBy;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is now handled by the built-in [`Object.groupBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy) method.

```js
const arr = [
    {type:"orange", title:"First"},
    {type:"orange", title:"Second"},
    {type:"banana", title:"Third"},
    {type:"banana", title:"Fourth"}
];
const res = Object.groupBy(arr, o => o.type);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: In type script, you can try like this (Object as any).groupBy(arr, o => o.type);

Answer (score 1):

You can also use
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy

It will serve your purpose

Answer (score 1):

**for an instance if we dont want to mention type then we can achieve like this**

```js
var arr = [
    {type:"orange", title:"First"},
    {type:"orange", title:"Second"},
    {type:"banana", title:"Third"},
    {type:"banana", title:"Fourth"}
];

const fun = (ar)=>{
  let temp ={}
for(e of ar){
  !temp[e.type] ? temp[e.type]=[e] : temp[e.type].push(e)
}
  return temp
}
console.log(fun(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Little tweak to @Watchmaker's answer to return array instead of object.:

```js
function groupBy(arr, key) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur[key]] = [...acc[cur[key]] || [], cur];
    return acc;
  }, []).filter(Boolean);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another **typescript** version

Originally inspired by the answer of @denolsson but I remove the property that is used as key as it is now redundant in the inner arrays.

Also changed and renamed some other things for better readability and to make the linter happy)

```
/**
 * Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/53632546/7869582
 */
private groupBy<T>(array: Array<T>, property: keyof T): { [key: string]: Array<T> } {
    return array.reduce(
        (objectToBeBuilt: { [key: string]: Array<T> }, arrayElem: T) => {
            
            const newOuterIdx = arrayElem[property] as unknown as string;
            
            if (!objectToBeBuilt[newOuterIdx]) {
                objectToBeBuilt[newOuterIdx] = [];
            }
            
            if (arrayElem[property]) {
                delete arrayElem[property];    
            }

            objectToBeBuilt[newOuterIdx]?.push(arrayElem);
            return objectToBeBuilt;
        },
        {}  // initial value of objectToBeBuild
    );
}
```

Example usage:

```
const resultGroupedByCustomer = this.groupBy(result.rows, "customer_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

An improvement of [@denolsson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5570739/denolsson)'s [TypeScript implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53632546/11041841) of the function:

```js
/**
 * Group an array of objects by a specified property.
 * @param {Array<T>} array - The array of objects to group.
 * @param {string} property - The property to group the objects by.
 * @returns {Object} An object where the keys are the unique values of the specified property and the values are arrays of objects with that property value.
 * @template T
 *
 * @example
 * const arr = [{type:"A"}, {type:"A"}, {type:"B"}];
 * const result = groupBy(arr, "type");
 * console.log(result); // Output: { A: [{type: "A"}, {type: "A"}], B: [{type: "B"}] }
 */
export function groupBy<T>(array: Array<T>, property: string): { [key: string]: Array<T> } {
    return array.reduce((memo: { [key: string]: Array<T> }, x: T) => {
        memo[x[property]] ||= [];
        memo[x[property]].push(x);
        return memo;
    }, {});
}
```

and the JavaScript version:

```js
export function groupBy(array, property) {
    return array.reduce((memo, x) => {
        memo[x[property]] ||= [];
        memo[x[property]].push(x);
        return memo;
    }, {});
}
```