# Angularjs Split array by object result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object

I have a array with objects like this:

```
{
  __v: 0,
  _id: "5835ced6ffb2476119a597b9",
  castvote: 1,
  time: "2016-11-23T17:16:06.676Z",
  userid: "57e0fa234f243f0710043f8f"
}
```

How can I make a new array that would filter them by the `castvote` - like an array containing the objects where `castvote` is 1, and one where `castvote` is 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in controller using **[$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)**,

```
$scope.castvoteOne = $filter('filter')($scope.results, {castvote: 1});
$scope.castvoteTwo = $filter('filter')($scope.results, {castvote: 2});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/duhugew/edit?html,js,output)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` and a `hash table` to group the array into an object with *key* as the `castvote` and *value* as the elements that have that particular `castvote`.

Now you can ***use `result[castvote]` to get the result for that particular `castvote`***

See demo below:

```js
var array=[{__v:0,_id:"5835ced6ffb2476119a597b9",castvote:1,time:"2016-11-23T17:16:06.676Z",userid:"57e0fa234f243f0710043f8f"},{__v:0,_id:"5835ced6ffb2476119a597b9",castvote:2,time:"2016-11-23T17:16:06.676Z",userid:"57e0fa234f243f0710043f8f"},{__v:0,_id:"5835ced6ffb2476119a597b9",castvote:1,time:"2016-11-23T17:16:06.676Z",userid:"57e0fa234f243f0710043f8f"}]

var result = array.reduce(function(hash){
  return function(p,c) {
    if(!hash[c.castvote]) {
      hash[c.castvote] = [];
      p[c.castvote] = hash[c.castvote];
    }
    hash[c.castvote].push(c);
    return p;
  };
}(Object.create(null)),{});

// use result[castvote] to get the result for that castvote
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696326/break-array-of-objects-into-separate-arrays-based-on-a-property)

You can use [Underscore's groupby](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) to do this generically by the type you want.

```
_.groupBy($scope.results, "castvote")
```