# how to put same value in same array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I am working in js and I got the response of one my array as follows:

**What structure of array I have:**

```
 [ 
  { test_name: 'comp 1 test 1',
    program_id: 1,
  },
  { test_name: 'comp 1 test 2',
    program_id: 1,
  },
  { test_name: 'complete 2 test 1',

    program_id: 2,
   } 
]
```

**But I want to get it like:**

```
 [ 
  [
  { test_name: 'comp 1 test 1',
    program_id: 1,
  },
  { test_name: 'comp 1 test 2',
    program_id: 1,
  }
  ],
  [
   { test_name: 'complete 2 test 1',

    program_id: 2,
   } 
  ]
]
```

I am getting data from database using Promises

```
 var req1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    db1.serialize(function() {

        var exer_names = [];
        var prog_status = 1;
        db1.each("SELECT  prog_name, prog_status,id  from programs Where prog_createdby = "+userId+" and prog_orgid = "+prog_orgid+" and prog_status = "+prog_status, function(err, row) {

        exer_names.push({id : row.id, prog_name: row.prog_name});

        },function(){

            resolve(exer_names);

        });
    });
});

var req2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    db1.serialize(function() {

        var test_names = [];

        db1.each("SELECT * from tests Where test_createdby = "+userId+" and org_id = "+prog_orgid+"", function(err, row) {

            test_names.push({test_name: row.test_name,test_alias: row.test_alias,test_createdby: row.test_createdby,sequences: row.sequences, duration: row.duration, program_id: row.prog_id, id: row.id });

        },function(){

             resolve(test_names);

        });

    });
});

  Promise.all([req1,req2]).then(function(programs, progerror) {
    programs[0].forEach(function(program){
    // what should be there??
    });

  }).catch(function(err) {

    console.log('Catch: ', err);

});
```

Comment: have you tried to use a group by clause?

Comment: that was not beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an 2D array indexed by program_id and fill it properly with 2 nested loop

```js
var input =  [
      {
        test_name: 'comp 1 test 1',
        program_id: 1,
      },
      {
        test_name: 'comp 1 test 2',
        program_id: 1,
      },
      {
        test_name: 'complete 2 test 1',
        program_id: 2,
      }
    ];
    output = input.map(x => x.program_id).filter((x,i,arr) => arr.indexOf(x) === i).map(x => [x]);
    output.forEach((x,i,arr) => {
      input.forEach(y => {
        if (y.program_id === x[0]) x.push(y);
      })
    });
    output = output.map(x => x.slice(1));
    console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can create arrays on the basis of program_id and then push those arrays into the parent array

```
var parent = [];
var child = [];
var another_child = [];
parent.push(child);
parent.push(another_child);
```

Comment: I am getting array from database

Comment: either you can change your db shema or you'll have to traverse the response array to be able to get the desired result

Comment: you need to apply little logic on program_id inside loop, wait

Comment: instead of applying loop on whole response, you should try dividing the response in multiple arrays on the basis of program_id. Then apply loop on those arrays to create child JSON objects.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696326/break-array-of-objects-into-separate-arrays-based-on-a-property
for that you can take help from here

Comment: let me check the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133640/discussion-between-deep-and-devesh-jadon).

Comment: Thanks @Davesh for your efforts, I have used your reference question. Thank you.