# How to reduce the repeated lines?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The below function does what it is supposed to do, but the code is repeated many times.

Is there any way to simplify the below code?

```
  getJiraOpenIssues(id:string) {
    return this.http.get<any>( apiUrl )
    .subscribe(response => {
      let open = response.issues.filter((status) => {
        return status.fields.status.name === 'Open';
      });

      let closed = response.issues.filter((status) => {
        return status.fields.status.name === 'Closed';
      });

      let resolved = response.issues.filter((status) => {
        return status.fields.status.name === 'Resolved';
      });

      let progress = response.issues.filter((status) => {
        return status.fields.status.name === 'In Progress';
      });

      let Total = open.length + closed.length + resolved.length + progress.length;
      console.log(Total);

    });
  }
```

Comment: Can't you simply use `response.issues.length` to get the total ?

Comment: What you actually filtering? which results are removed from it?

Comment: i get a bulk response from the API, in that response I want to count how many are open,closed and resolved.

Comment: You could also you a switch statement

Comment: The accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696326/break-array-of-objects-into-separate-arrays-based-on-a-property looks like the cleanest solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [break array of objects into separate arrays based on a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696326/break-array-of-objects-into-separate-arrays-based-on-a-property)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this.

```
   getJiraOpenIssues(id:string) {
        const desired = ['Open', 'Closed', 'Resolved', 'In Progress'];
        return this.http.get<any>( apiUrl )
        .subscribe(response => {
          let items = response.issues.filter((status) => {
            return desired.includes(status.fields.status.name);
          });

          console.log(item.length);

        });
      }
```

---

**EDIT**
Suggestion:

Once I had used JIRA, I can consider using `JIRA JQL` API, documentation url below.

I guess there must be an API where you can pass that we need the issue statue which you really required instead of filtering at your end. Moreover `JQL` execute on the database it will do the filtering job more efficiently.

https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/

Comment: This one is returning just the total , I want the total for each items as wll

Comment: `console.log(item)` instead of `console.log(item.length)`

Comment: Yes, But in that case i'll have to make multiple API calls

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like

```
getJiraOpenIssues(id:string) {
  const fn = (response, state) => {
    return response.issues.filter((status) => status.fields.status.name === state);
  };

  return this.http.get<any>( apiUrl )
  .subscribe(response => {
    let open = fn(response, 'Open');
    let closed = fn(response, 'Closed');
    let resolved = fn(response, 'Resolved');
    let progress = fn(response, 'In Progress');

    let Total = open.length + closed.length + resolved.length + progress.length;
    console.log(Total);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getJiraOpenIssues(id:string) {
    return this.http.get<any>( apiUrl )
    .subscribe(response => {
        let open = this.responseFilter(response, 'Open');

        let closed = this.responseFilter(response, 'Closed');

        let resolved = this.responseFilter(response, 'Resolved');

        let progress = this.responseFilter(response, 'In Progress');

        let Total = open.length + closed.length + resolved.length + progress.length;
        console.log(Total);

    });
}

responseFilter (response, filter) {
    fv = response.issues.filter((status) => {
        return status.fields.status.name === filter;
    });
    return fv;
}
```