# Altering an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects like this ...

```
[
{ id:1, t1_id: 345, t1_val: "small", t2_id: 456, t2_val: "med", t3_id: 146, t3_val: "lrg"  },
{ id:2, t1_id: 983, t1_val: "small", t2_id: 657, t2_val: "med", t3_id: 548, t3_val: "lrg"  },
{ id:3, t1_id: 479, t1_val: "small", t2_id: 256, t2_val: "med", t3_id: 326, t3_val: "lrg"  }
]
```

I am looking to alter this array to something like this ...

```
[
{ id:1, t1_id: 345, t1_val: "small"},
{ id:1, t2_id: 345, t2_val: "med" },
{ id:1, t3_id: 146, t3_val: "lrg"  },


{ id:2, t1_id: 983, t1_val: "small" },
{ id:2, t2_id: 657, t2_val: "med",},
{ id:2, t3_id: 548, t3_val: "lrg"  },

{ id:3, t1_id: 479, t1_val: "small"  },
{ id:3, t2_id: 256, t2_val: "med", },
{ id:3, t3_id: 326, t3_val: "lrg"  }
]
```

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this ? I have looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696326/break-array-of-objects-into-separate-arrays-based-on-a-property) but not sure how to implement this in my case? ES6 solutions are preferred.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: What version of JavaScript are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function filterData(arr) {

  var rs = []
  arr.forEach(function(e) {

    rs.push({
      'id': e['id'],
      't1_id': e['t1_id'],
      't1_val': e['t1_val']
    });

    rs.push({
      'id': e['id'],
      't2_id': e['t2_id'],
      't2_val': e['t2_val']
    });

    rs.push({
      'id': e['id'],
      't3_id': e['t3_id'],
      't3_val': e['t3_val']
    });
  })

  return rs;
}

var x = [{
    id: 1,
    t1_id: 345,
    t1_val: "small",
    t2_id: 456,
    t2_val: "med",
    t3_id: 146,
    t3_val: "lrg"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    t1_id: 983,
    t1_val: "small",
    t2_id: 657,
    t2_val: "med",
    t3_id: 548,
    t3_val: "lrg"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    t1_id: 479,
    t1_val: "small",
    t2_id: 256,
    t2_val: "med",
    t3_id: 326,
    t3_val: "lrg"
  }
];

console.log(filterData(x))
```

Comment: @Slyper you should read the first comment of your question its showing you, that in which standard the stackoverflow community expect questions from users.

Comment: @Slyper you can't expect anyone to upvote it as it's not showing any code or does not provide anything we can help you with... it's just about writing you a piece of code because you don't know how to do that. You haven't provide the minimal information needed like if the javascript version you use.

Comment: I did @azad, I tried to implement a solution from another post, but it didn't worked. This is not the first time I have posted on Stackoverflow ...I have posted hundreds of questions before. It was one of the moments when you are just stuck .... but in the end who cares ....!

Comment: @Slyper at least you could have post which way you tried to solve the problem