# Insert td in blank Angulajs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to programming but I am stuck with a project in Angularjs, it is the simple task of adding a blank row without any data to an html table so that you can notice the separation of the group by the Quality field and, therefore, See it in a more orderly way.

When the quality data changes, the row must be inserted to separate the following information. It is understood?

HTML View
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEcnl.png)

[image]

I have drawn a red line where I want to insert the blank rows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc3HC.png)

[image]

Comment: Don't use images to show your code. Post the relevant part here, strip out irrelevant parts.

Comment: Images of code are difficult to read and impossible to use to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to group your `pieces` array of objects by `quality` by using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14696535/9939798.

Sample code for your controller:

```
function groupBy(arr, property) {
    return arr.reduce(function (memo, x) {
        if (!memo[x[property]]) { memo[x[property]] = []; }
        memo[x[property]].push(x);
        return memo;
    }, {});
}

$scope.pieces = [
    { quality: "602P10D", status: "Dispatched" },
    { quality: "602P10D", status: "Dispatched" },
    { quality: "6025098", status: "Dispatched" },
    { quality: "6025098", status: "Dispatched" }
];

$scope.grouped = groupBy($scope.pieces, 'quality');
```

Sample table markup:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Quality</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="pieces in grouped">
        <tr ng-repeat="data in pieces">
            <td>{{ data.quality }}</td>
            <td>{{ data.status }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><!-- This is the separator --></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/75ez2nkw/1/

Comment: it works thank you very much, you are the best I really appreciate your help, can I ask you another question? If you want to perform the line break when you change one of the four variables, such as "Quality", "Design", "Shadow_1", "Shadow_2".
How should I leave the function?

Comment: You have to watch changes on your pieces variable then apply the grouping function accordingly. Fiddle here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/u9gph7L6/)