# In Javascript, is there a way to split an array into multiple arrays based on object property?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array of people:

```
const people = [
  { name: 'Tom Hiddleston', country: 'UK' },
  { name: 'Joe Biden', country: 'USA' },
  { name: 'James Bond', country: 'UK' },
  { name: 'Barack Obama', country: 'USA' },
  { name: 'Dolph Lundgren', country: 'SWEDEN' },
];
```

Now I want to break this array into multiple arrays based on the **country** property.

Basically I want a magic function that does the following:

```
const peopleGroupedByCountry = magicFunction(people);
console.log(peopleGroupedByCountry);

// Should log the following:
[
  [
    { name: 'Tom Hiddleston', country: 'UK' },
    { name: 'James Bond', country: 'UK' },
  ],
  [
    { name: 'Joe Biden', country: 'USA' },
    { name: 'Barack Obama', country: 'USA' },
  ],
  [
    { name: 'Dolph Lundgren', country: 'SWEDEN' },
  ]
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696326/break-array-of-objects-into-separate-arrays-based-on-a-property

Comment: @PranayNailwal Well that link leads to answers using underscore and jquery, not what I was after. Terry Lennox answer here is in pure vanilla js, and works perfectly.

Comment: I would recommend Terry's answer since it's much modern and elegant while the referenced Q&A is about 8 years

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Array.reduce to do this, we create an object with keys for each country.

We can then use Object.values to get this as an array.

```js
const people = [
    { name: 'Tom Hiddleston', country: 'UK' },
    { name: 'Joe Biden', country: 'USA' },
    { name: 'James Bond', country: 'UK' },
    { name: 'Barack Obama', country: 'USA' },
    { name: 'Dolph Lundgren', country: 'SWEDEN' },
];

const grouped = Object.values(people.reduce((acc, item) => {
    // Append the item to the array for each country
    acc[item.country] = [...(acc[item.country] || []), item];
    return acc;
}, {}))

console.log(grouped)
```

Comment: It would be better to add another parameter to assign which key should be the reference to group with

Comment: Works perfectly, and in vanilla js as well! Unlike whoever closed my question as already answered, referring to a 8 year old post with accepted answers using jQuery and underscore, which is not relevant to my question. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Also enjoyed this answer vs the referred "already answered" post