# store fruits array in two new array based on property in Reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have an array like this:

```
fruits:[
       {name:"Orange", Title:"Fruits", Quantity: "4"},
       {name:"Apple", Title:"Fruits", Quantity: "7"},
       {name:"Grape", Title:"Fruits", Quantity: "4"},
       {name:"Banana", Title:"Fruits", Quantity: "4"},
    ];
```

I want separate and store fruits array into two different array:

```
a:[
   {name:"Orange", Title:"Fruits", Quantity: "4"},
   {name:"Grape", Title:"Fruits", Quantity: "4"},
   {name:"Banana", Title:"Fruits", Quantity: "4"},
  ];

b:[{name:"Apple", Title:"Fruits", Quantity: "7"},];
```

How I can solve it? Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: based on which property ?

Comment: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696326/break-array-of-objects-into-separate-arrays-based-on-a-property) may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b = fruits.filter(fruit => fruit.name == 'Apple')
```

or

```
const { fruitsToStoreInB } = props
b = fruits.filter(fruit => fruitsToStoreInB.includes(fruit.name))
```

Have a look at the [MDN documentation for arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to see what you can do.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need to filter object based on quantity.

```js
let fruits = [
    {name:"Orange", Title:"Fruits", Quantity: "4"},
    {name:"Apple", Title:"Fruits", Quantity: "7"},
    {name:"Grape", Title:"Fruits", Quantity: "4"},
    {name:"Banana", Title:"Fruits", Quantity: "4"},
 ];
 let obj  = {};
 let result = [];
 for(let fruit of fruits){
    obj[fruit.Quantity] = fruit.Quantity;
 }
 for(let o in obj){
   result.push(fruits.filter(fruit=>fruit.Quantity === obj[o]));
 }
 console.log(result);
```