# Separate an array in another arrays depending of item status in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript array with several records and some items in each record that only have 2 different statuses, on and off.
I want to go through this array and separate it into several other arrays depending on the status, but when I find a status different from the previous one, I create a new array. Example:

```
main_array = [{'date': '2023-10-02 00:01:00', 'status': 'on'},{'date': '2023-10-02 00:02:00', 'status': 'on'},{'date': '2023-10-02 00:03:00', 'status': 'off'},{'date': '2023-10-02 00:04:00', 'status': 'off'},{'date': '2023-10-02 00:05:00', 'status': 'off'},{'date': '2023-10-02 00:06:00', 'status': 'on'},{'date': '2023-10-02 00:07:00', 'status': 'on'},{'date': '2023-10-02 00:08:00', 'status': 'on'},{'date': '2023-10-02 00:09:00', 'status': 'off'},{'date': '2023-10-02 00:10:00', 'status': 'off'}];


array1 = [{'date': '2023-10-02 00:01:00', 'status': 'on'},{'date': '2023-10-02 00:02:00', 'status': 'on'}];

array2 = [{'date': '2023-10-02 00:03:00', 'status': 'off'},{'date': '2023-10-02 00:04:00', 'status': 'off'},{'date': '2023-10-02 00:05:00', 'status': 'off'}];

array3 = [{'date': '2023-10-02 00:06:00', 'status': 'on'},{'date': '2023-10-02 00:07:00', 'status': 'on'},{'date': '2023-10-02 00:08:00', 'status': 'on'}];

array4 = [{'date': '2023-10-02 00:09:00', 'status': 'off'},{'date': '2023-10-02 00:10:00', 'status': 'off'}];
```

This is a little example in an array with more of 1000 elements.

How can i do this?

Comment: please make/show your attempt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14696326/3001761, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use Array `reduce()` method to iterate the `main_array` and push each item to an array in the accumulator object while incrementing the array name when status changes. Here is an example:

```js
const main_array = [
  { date: "2023-10-02 00:01:00", status: "on" },
  { date: "2023-10-02 00:02:00", status: "on" },
  { date: "2023-10-02 00:03:00", status: "off" },
  { date: "2023-10-02 00:04:00", status: "off" },
  { date: "2023-10-02 00:05:00", status: "off" },
  { date: "2023-10-02 00:06:00", status: "on" },
  { date: "2023-10-02 00:07:00", status: "on" },
  { date: "2023-10-02 00:08:00", status: "on" },
  { date: "2023-10-02 00:09:00", status: "off" },
  { date: "2023-10-02 00:10:00", status: "off" },
];

let stat; // Track status
let index = 0; // Array index

const result = main_array.reduce((acc, i) => {
  if (i.status === stat) {
    acc["array" + index].push(i);
  } else {
    index++;
    acc["array" + index] = [];
    acc["array" + index].push(i);
  }

  stat = i.status;

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```